# I have a UK passport, can I re-enter Hong Kong every month and stay for 6 months?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, hong-kong

I hold a UK passport and that lets me stay in Hong Kong for 6 months on a tourist visa. During that time I would work remotely for a company based in the UK.

So if I come to Hong Kong stay for 6 months, then go back to London for a month, and then go back to Hong Kong, will they let me in for another 6 months?

Also, does anyone know how does that looks like from tax residency perspective?

Comment: I think you should ask at Expatriates Stack Exchange. You may be violating labor and tax laws if you work in HK while you are there on a tourist visa.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just 6 months, 1 month, 6 months, it will be fine. However, if you're planning to do this for a number of years, I would advise against it. There's no better flag for SCL (Suspected Casual Labor, the stamp they put on your passport if they suspect something fishy) than this.

What you do instead is from the time you arrive in HK, establish a baseline of frequent entries and exits, and acquire as soon as possible the [eChannel for frequent visitors barcode](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/echannel_visitors.html). Once you have that, you can enter and leave HK via the eChannel, the electronic gates. Unsupervised. Which means you can stay forever in HK on tourist visas.

Comment: That -1 needs some 'splaining...